# PowerShell $args probleme

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I try to make this script working

```
Function test_var
{$return = 0
foreach ($arg in $args)
{ 
if (!$arg) {(Write-Host "ERROR : $arg.Name Missing variable" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black)
$return = 1}
}
return $return
}
```

When I call the function with arguments

```
test_var "c" "$b" "$a"
```

The function work correctly but I can't display the name of the actual `$arg` because the value was empty .

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is the expected output and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: $a = "test1" $b="test2" #$c="test3"

Comment: i need to see ERROR : $C Missing variable i have those varriable declared in anather text file but actuly i can juste see ERROR : .Name Missing variable

Comment: The function can't "know" the variable names that you passed to it. Declare your parameters like suggested by Martin Brandl

Comment: like i said i have all my variable in one text file and i need to check if those variable existe really in my file. i try this function test_var "$c" "$b" "$a" 
and i nedd to cheack all those varriable with a simple script

Comment: So the function know all those varriable

Comment: It knows the variable *values*, not the name you use for them.

Comment: OK so there is no solution for this issue i need to display the name of the arg in message erreur

Comment: No. If you explain what practical/actual problem you're trying to solve we might be able to help you

Comment: i need to create a function to check if a predefined variable exist in external text file

the text file contain

$a = "abd"
$b = "cdf"
$c="aze"
In my script i call the text file with . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $I ) and i create this function

Comment: the function work fine when i make a modification like
$a = "abd"
$b = "cdf"
#$c="aze"     and i have my error message ERROR : Missing variable ==> but the name of empty variable is missing

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a new question *with those details*, and please describe exactly what you expect, what happens and what you mean when you say things like "works fine". I'd suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: thx  you really help me with your commant

Answer (score 2):

Like Mathias mentioned in his comment, your question is a bit unclear. However:

PowerShell already has a *built-in* mechanism to validate arguments. Instead of using `$args` consider using predefined arguments for your function. In the following example, the argument `$a` is *mandatory*  whereas `$b` is optional:

```
function Test-Var
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $a,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        $b
    )

}
```