# How can I create function check with $args

Tags: powershell

I declare all variable in `var.ps1` like this:

```
$a = "aa"
$b = "bb"
```

In the second script `check.ps1` I try to create a function to check if the argument passed exist in `var.ps1` something like this:

```
check "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

I need to use args in my function.

Could you please give me any suggestion?

Comment: like this exemple i need to have a message erreur ==> $c does not exist

Comment: Dot source can do that followed by if else

Comment: Use `get-Variable` inside that script. Also use single quotes when passing variable names inside your function, or else they will expand into their values.

Comment: i try thid $a = Get-Variable "$args"  but i have this erreur message Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name '-Source $destinationFolder'.

Comment: This looks a lot like the two questions you posted on Tuesday. As the duplicate link on the other answers explain, you can't infer what the original variable name was that was passed to the function. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish and why if you want help.

Comment: Thx mathias for your help i try to use Get-Variable $arg also i use variable directly when i call function and it work                                            foreach ($arg in $args)
{$d = Get-Variable $arg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$d.Value) {(Write-Host "[ERROR] Variable $arg is unset"}}

Comment: Please answer my question: What are you trying to accomplish, and *why*?

Comment: How is this question different from the [last](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43346883/1630171) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43341573/1630171) questions you asked?

Comment: thx Ansgar Wiechers and Mathias R. Jessen for your answers i flow the exemple of Ansgar and my script work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you want this and I'd probably solve it another way, but to answer your question, you can try the sample below.

Remember to use literal strings (single quotes) for values with a leading `$` to avoid them being treated as a variable. If not, PowerShell will try to replace the variables with it's value (or nothing if it's not defined), which means that `Check-Variables` won't get the variable names. The following solution accepts both `'a'` and `'$a'`.

Var.ps1

```
$a = "aa"
$b = "bb"
```

Check.ps1

```
#Dot-sourcing var.ps1 which is located in the same folder as Check.ps1
#Loads variables into the current scope so every function in Check.ps1 can access them
. "$PSScriptRoot\var.ps1"

function Check-Variables {

    foreach ($name in $args) {
        #Remove leading $
        $trimmedname = $name -replace '^\$'

        if(-not (Get-Variable -Name $trimmedname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            Write-Host "ERROR: Variable `$$trimmedname is not defined"
        }
    }
}

Check-Variables '$a' "b" '$c'
```

Demo:

```
PS> C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Check.ps1
ERROR: Variable $c is not defined
```